# Iterate and compare first item to all items in dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Please help, I can't seem to find a way to do this. I am working on a web science project and  this is my third project with python.

I need to compare the first item in dictionary with all the other items in the same dictionary, but my other items are dictionaries.

For example, I have a dictionary that has the following values:

```
{'25': {'Return of the Jedi (1983)': 5.0},
 '42': {'Batman (1989)': 3.0, 'E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial (1982)': 5.0},
 '8': {'Return of the Jedi (1983)': 5.0 },'542': {'Alice in Wonderland (1951)': 3.0, 'Blade Runner (1982)': 4.0}, '7': {'Alice in Wonderland (1951)': 3.0,'Blade Runner (1982)': 4.0}}
```

So I need to see if the keys '25' and '42' contain same movie "Return of the Jedi" in this case, then if '25' and '8' have the same movie and so on. I they do, I need to know how many movies overlap.

This is an example of the dictionary, the whole dictionary contains 1000 keys and the sub-dictionaries are way bigger also.

I tried to iterate, compare dictionaries, make copies, merge, join, but I can´t seem to grasp how I can do this.

Help please!

The thing is that I still can't compare both subdictionaries because I need to find the keys that have at least 2 of the same movies as a whole.

Comment: Are you looking for just the number of overlapping movies?

Comment: What do you mean by "first" item in a dictionary?  A dictionary is unordered.  Do you want the entry with the smallest key value?

Comment: Well, whatever the first item of the dictionary is, it doesn't matter.

Comment: For Blender, I was looking for the key that has more overlapping movies with other keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> dic={'25': {'Return of the Jedi (1983)': 5.0}, '42': {'Batman (1989)': 3.0, 'E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial (1982)': 5.0}, '8': {'Return of the Jedi (1983)': 5.0 }}
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c=Counter(movie  for v in dic.values() for movie in v)

>>> [k for k,v in c.items() if v>1] #returns the name of movies repeated more than once
['Return of the Jedi (1983)']
>>> c
Counter({'Return of the Jedi (1983)': 2,
         'Batman (1989)': 1,
         'E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial (1982)': 1})
```

To get the keys related to each movie you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> movie_keys=defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in dic.items(): 
    for movie in v:
        movie_keys[movie].append(k)
...         
>>> movie_keys
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Batman (1989)': ['42'], 'Return of the Jedi (1983)': ['25', '8'], 'E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial (1982)': ['42']})
```

Comment: Wow, ok, but now that I have the list of who has seen which movie, I would like to look at the first answer of the dictionary, say Batman, and compare it to the second answer of that dictionary, Return of the Jedi, so that I can see if they both have 42. And then do the same for Batman and ET.

Comment: @Mirimari before posting a question please make sure what you want as output, you're just demanding  more and more things in the same question. If you've a new question then post it as a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought it was the same.

Comment: @Mirimari your original question was about "how many movies overlap" which I answered, you can always post a new question(but try yourself first). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a "first" item in a dictionary, but you could find all the keys that contain a given movie with something like this:

```
movies = {}
for k in data:
    for movie in data[k]:
        movies.setdefault(movie, []).append(k)
```

The output movies would look like:

```
{'Return of the Jedi (1983)': [25, 8], 'Batman (1989)': [42], ...}
```

Comment: Unless you are using a very old Python, it's neater to use `collections.defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Thanks! But after that I wanted to know how to compare movie_Title1 to movie_title2 and see if both of them contain the same ids inside, if they do save them, then compare movie_title1 to movie_title3 and see ids again, for all the movieTitles in the main dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will only return a dictionary containing `'title',['offender1',...]` pairs for movies which are seen more than once, i.e **not** `'E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial (1982)'` but `'Return of the Jedi (1983)'` would be reported. This can be changed by simply returning `overlaps` in the solution rather than the result of a dictionary comprehension.

Where d is:

```
d = {'25': {'Return of the Jedi (1983)': 5.0},
     '42': {'Batman (1989)': 3.0, 'E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial (1982)': 5.0},
     '8': {'Return of the Jedi (1983)': 5.0 },
     '542': {'Alice in Wonderland (1951)': 3.0, 'Blade Runner (1982)': 4.0},
     '7': {'Alice in Wonderland (1951)': 3.0,'Blade Runner (1982)': 4.0}
     }
```

The following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
def findOverlaps(d):
    overlaps = defaultdict(list)
    for (parentKey,children) in d.items(): #children is the dictionary containing movie_title,rating pairs
        for childKey in children.keys(): #we're only interested in the titles not the ratings, hence keys() not items()
            overlaps[childKey].append(parentKey) #add the parent 'id' where the movie_title came from
    return dict(((overlap,offenders) for (overlap,offenders) in overlaps.items() if len(offenders) > 1)) #return a dictionary, only if the movie title had more than one 'id' associated with it
print(findOverlaps(d))
```

Produces:

```
>>> 
{'Blade Runner (1982)': ['7', '542'], 'Return of the Jedi (1983)': ['25', '8'], 'Alice in Wonderland (1951)': ['7', '542']}
```

The reasoning behind the code:

each entry in d represents `id : { movie_title1: rating, movie_title2: rating }`. Now say `movie_title1` occurred in the **value** associated with two or more *separate* `id` keys. We would want to store

1. The `move_title` of the movie which was seen twice or more.
2. The `id`'s key, associated with the *value* in which the movie was seen.

Hence we would like a resultant dictionary like so

`{ move_title1: {'id1','id2'}, movie_title2: {'id2','id5'}`

Comment: Thanks! But after that I wanted to know how to compare movie_Title1 to movie_title2  and see if both of them contain the same ids inside, if they do save them, then compare movie_title1 to movie_title3 and see ids again, for all the movieTitles in the main dictionary.